# Need some kind of enum which is extensible by database (using Spring 3.2, Hibernate 4.2)

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, enums, extends

we've got the following situation in our application:

- We have `UserGroup`s
- These can be created by the user
- The user can map some `User`s to a given `UserGroup` (n:m relationship)

Now we need some special `UserGroup`s which we can access in Java Code. So when it's all done, the user should see a mix of his own created `UserGroup`s and our hard coded groups (which of course cannot be deleted).

The first idea was to put those extra groups in the database when it's created and simply rely on the fact that they are in there, but **I** think that's bad practice. (because the system will crash if they get deleted or renamed)

The second idea was to have an `enum` for those special groups. Which would be pretty fine. But of course you can't extend an enum and place additional values in it.

I think, it should be some enum in code where we can place our hard coded groups (for easy referencing), and it has to be somehow connected to the database, so the user can do his `User <-> UserGroup` mapping (for his own created groups and our special groups).

So we need something else, but **what**?

### EDIT:

We've now chosen an alternative as a solution, which won't disturb the *normal* database designs:

```
  USER             GROUP_USER             GROUP              ACTION
--------        ----------------        ---------        --------------
id | ...        groupId | userId        id | name        groupId | enum
```

As you can see, we don't try to put some static groups inside the group table, but instead now we expose those internal actions to the user interface, and now the user can say: "Action A belongs to Group X". This has several advantages: The user can choose the name for the group and he can also use more than one group.

So the `ACTION` table is basically and `@CollectionOfElements` inside the `GROUP` entity.

It's not the exact solution for the problem above, but in our case it solves the problem in a nice way and that's all that counts `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first idea was to put those extra groups in the database when it's created and simply rely on the fact that they are in there, but I think that's bad practice. (because the system will crash if they get deleted or renamed)

Your application will also crash if the database is not there at all, or if tables and columns used by your application are renamed for example.

To me, the presence of these rows, with the correct IDs or names, is simply a prerequisite, just like the presence of tables and columns of the right type.

Just make sure to document the fact that these rows must be present. Make sure that the application doesn't allow renaming or deleting them and, if you're really concerned about someone deleting these rows, check that all the hard-coded IDs/names you're using in the code have their corresponding row in the database at startup.

Comment: Maybe it won't really crash, but some functionality won't be available, maybe some exceptions are thrown and it may be pretty annoying for the user. So I thought there must be some other way of mixing those things... So having some fixed content (accessible via enum) and some dynamic content which can be created/deleted by the user.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The rows are a prerequisite for your app to function as it should. Not having them is a configuration bug, just like forgetting to add a required column to a table. Frankly, I don't see the probem in using some hard-coded IDs in the application code if you own the data. It's just your responsibility to make sure the data is present.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. So I should maybe insert at application start the enum to database (if not already present). And then use everything as usual.

Comment: I think that's the only way, since the hardcoded values have to be always in the database, but then I've got to write some code which prevents those values from being deleted. Annoying... Do you think working with `@Entity` inheritance could be a solution? `CustomUserGroup extends UserGroup` and `HardCodedUserGroup extends UserGroup` and then just fetch `UserGroup` to get both entries at a time. Just have to find out if it's possible to have a unique constraint over both tables...

Comment: You could do that, but I don't see how it would prevent the deletion of the rows (either directly in the database or from the application, through JPA).

Comment: It would, because I can make the `UserGroup` read-only and just expose the functionality to create new `CustomUserGroup`s. Hmm... yeah, somehow it must be possible to fill the `HardCodedUserGroup` table. Any idea? `;)`

Comment: Still don't get you. `em.remove(someUserGroup)` will remove the group, whatever its type is. It's a matter of correctness in the code. You could do that using a subclass, but a flag in the entity can be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, i got your point... I will think a bit over this. But I'll also accept your answer. Seems to be the only solution. I just have to think about the implementation.